# Make Thunderbird to check for mails when it is closed

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to make Thunderbird to check for new mails even when it is *closed*. Currently for me it only checks for new mails when is open or when is minimized.

For example in Windows, Mailbird is such a mail client that checks for new mails even when it is closed. But its icon still exists in system tray.

Comment: @markkirby Thanks for your help, but that *FireTray* adds another icon to my tray but I would prefer that original icon only, not two icons for mail client!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extension you can use " MinimizeToTray revived 1.1.2", it is popular and highly praised, it should fit your needs

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/